# Boolean filter on nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, boolean

I'm having some troubles using boolean operators with nested objects.
This is my mapping:

```
   "IP": {
        "properties": {
          "ip": {
            "type": "ip"
          }
        },
        "type": "nested"
      }
```

I want to get documents which contains exactly two specified ips and maybe more.

Suppose that my document has the followinh ips:

```
    DOC 1
        192.168.1.0
        192.168.0.1
        10.0.0.9

    DOC 2
       192.168.0.1
```

I want to retrieve only DOC 1 by searching with this filter:

```
      "bool": {
        "must": {
          "terms": {
            "IP.ip": [
              "192.168.0.1",
              "10.0.0.9"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
```

The problem is that both DOC 1 and DOC2 are retrieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `"execution":"and"` on your [terms filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html#_execution_mode) like this:

```
{
   "filter": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "terms": {
                  "ip": [
                     "192.168.0.1",
                     "10.0.0.9"
                  ],
                  "execution": "and"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is some code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/d6b5f4e4c0d2977a04b1795f4bbb0503f6365dfe

**EDIT:** Nested version (I misunderstood the question).

This query should give you what you need, assuming your index is set up the way I set up mine for testing (see code below). There need to be two `nested` clauses in the `must` list since we are looking for a document that contains two different nested documents, one with each IP.

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "filter": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "ips",
                  "filter": {
                     "term": {
                        "ip": "192.168.0.1"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "ips",
                  "filter": {
                     "term": {
                        "ip": "10.0.0.9"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used to set it up:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/cd3a0ec61cb1348d5cc2bd1ef444f4898f6d8e57

Comment: nice did not realize this option existed

Comment: Thank you for you answer, Solan. But I'm still having the same problem, even using the "execution" statement. The difference between mine and your example is that I use nested objects. Have you tested your code with nested ips?

Comment: Ah, I see. I misunderstood the question, I guess. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you Solan, that was exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "minimum_match" with "terms" query

```
"bool": {
    "must": {
      "terms": {
        "IP.ip": [
          "192.168.0.1",
          "10.0.0.9"
        ],
        "minimum_match" :"100%"
      }
    }
  }
```

This would return the record which contains all the values in terms query.