# Elasticsearch boolean search in nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch

I've the following nested index structure:

```
"sector_parametric": [

        {
            "sector": [
                "2"
            ],
            "experience": 1.7,
            "adv_business_sector_id": "637"
        },
        {
            "sector": [
                "1",
                "2",
                "10003"
            ],
            "experience": 2.7,
            "adv_business_sector_id": "642"
        }
]
```

It's easy to write the following query:
[Boolean filter on nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205748/boolean-filter-on-nested-objectsa)

But I need the documents, with sector 1 AND 2, not necessarily in the same nested object.
So I've to find the following

```
"sector_parametric": [

        {
            "sector": [
                "2"
            ],
            "experience": 1.7,
            "adv_business_sector_id": "637"
        },
        {
            "sector": [
                "1",
                "10003"
            ],
            "experience": 2.7,
            "adv_business_sector_id": "642"
        }
]
```

And this document too

```
"sector_parametric": [

        {
            "sector": [
                "2"
            ],
            "experience": 1.7,
            "adv_business_sector_id": "637"
        },
        {
            "sector": [
                "1",
                 "2"
                "10003"
            ],
            "experience": 2.7,
            "adv_business_sector_id": "642"
        }
]
```

Comment: so, are you trying to find sector 1 OR 2?

Comment: The solution is to store separately the all the nested sector values in an array.